# How to install hieroglyph

Tags: installing, installing-fonts

I must work (under Windows 10, MikTeX and TeXMaker) with Egyptian hieroglyphs that are not managed by the package [`hieroglf`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hieroglf). [`hieroglyph`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hieroglyph) is able to do so, but it must be installed manually and the documentation seems to be much outdated. In the corresponding doc in particular (3.1), it reads:

> The next step is to run:
>
> `MiKTeX\miktex\config\config.bat`
>
> Then make sure the sesh.exe file i[s] in your path.

`MiKTeX\miktex\config\config.bat` doesn't seem to exist and I also can't find any `sesh.exe` file.
Is there any detailed document explaining how to install `hieroglyph` with Windows?

Comment: The sesh file is part of the hieroglyph-package. In https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/hieroglyph you find an archive HieroTeX_3_5_tgz.  Sesh.exe is inside HieroTeX-3.5.tgz\HieroTeX-3.5.tar\HieroTeX\Seshnesu\.  On MikTeX side I can't help, but I would try it with a refresh of the ls-r-Database.

Comment: My antivirus software issues an alert for HieroTeX_3_5.tgz. Could be a false positive, but I can't tell.

Comment: Probably innocent, though ...

Comment: The Windows binary is pre-compiled, so you probably don't even have to make it - just install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As cfr has said, it is very simple:

- the line about `MiKTeX\miktex\config\config.bat` can be skipped;
- Sesh.exe is inside HieroTeX-3.5.tgz\HieroTeX-3.5.tar\HieroTeX\Seshnesu.