# Error using the `hieroglyph` package

Tags: installing-fonts

I am trying to use the `hieroglyph` package (variously known as `hiero` or `HieroTeX`) for typesetting Ancient Egyptian hieroglyphs. Having read related questions [[1]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377937/installing-hieroglyph-package) [[2]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451530/hierotex-by-serge-rosmorduc-manual-installation) [[3]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345762/how-to-install-hieroglyph) I followed the following steps:

1. Download the ZIP archive from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/hieroglyph?lang=en).
2. Unzip and use WinZip to unzip the two TGZ files and their contents.
3. Copy the two `texmf` folders into a single folder, which I called `texmf-hiero`.
4. Using the MikTeX Console, added the `textmf-hiero` folder to the list of root directories.
5. Using the MikTeX Console, ran 'Refresh file name database' and 'Refresh font map files'.
6. Attempted to run this minimal example:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{egypto}
    \usepackage[psfonts]{hiero}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{hieroglyph}
    A1 \end{hieroglyph}
    \end{document}
```

The console output is:

```
entering extended mode
(C:/Users/dbmag/Documents/latex/hiero.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-05-11>
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size12.clo))
(C:/Users/dbmag/Documents/Egyptian/texmf-hiero\tex/latex/hierotex\egypto.sty
egypto.sty V2.0a (second NUMBERED VERSION :-)
(C:/Users/dbmag/Documents/Egyptian/texmf-hiero\tex/latex/hierotex\EgypUtil.sty)
(C:/Users/dbmag/Documents/Egyptian/texmf-hiero\tex/latex/hierotex\OT1diacr.fd))
 (C:/Users/dbmag/Documents/Egyptian/texmf-hiero\tex/latex/hierotex\hiero.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def)))Running miktex-makemf.exe...


Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed.



The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:



  C:\Users\dbmag\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.log

Running miktex-hbf2gf.exe...
Couldn't open `Hier.cfg'



hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4)




Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\dbmag\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-maketfm.log

! Font \GA=HieroA scaled 1440 not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.136 \@declareHieroglyphicFonts
                                
?
```

Does anybody have any insight into how to resolve this? I'm happy to provide any other information that would be useful.

Comment: last time I tried hieroglyph it worked like this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/546542/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you very much for that (which I'd managed not to find despite spending a good while searching). I now still have a problem getting the `sesh.exe` preprocessor to operate but the font issue seems to be resolved.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If you were to post an answer I'd happily mark it as accepted; alternatively perhaps this question should be marked as a duplicate? But your answer at the other question hasn't been marked as accepted...

Comment: I would say duplicate is fine. I will vote for it.